# Uniqueness of solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a_0,a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that the ODE:

$$y'''(t) + y"(t) + y'(t) + y(t) = 0$$

with initial conditions:

$$y(0) = a_0,\:y'(0) = a_1,\:y''(0) = a_2$$ has a unique solution. Here $y^{(n)}(t)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $y$. Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll find that people here are a lot more receptive if you show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

As the equation is linear, assuming that you found two distinct solutions, their difference must also be a solution and it verifies the quiet initial conditions $y''(0)=y'(0)=y(0)=0$.

Then by the ODE, $y^{(n)}=-y^{(n-1)}-y^{(n-2)}-y^{(n-3)}$ so that $y$ is infinitely differentiable and all derivatives are $0$ at the origin. Hence by the Taylor development, $y$ is identically zero.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the above differential equation in eliminator form, (using D notation) we have

$$(D^3 + D^2 + D + 1)y = 0$$
$$\implies (D+1)(D^2+1)y = 0$$

The general solution to this would be $y = ce^{-x}(A\sin x + B\cos x)$

You will have three equations in three variables, basis your initial conditions, which should admit a unique solution

Comment: You should also prove that you have the most general solution.

Comment: By the way, as written your system with $A,B,C$ is once indeterminate, shedding shadow on your uniqueness argument. Not counting that the solution is wrong !